# Problemas con el uso de Threads en Python

Tags: python, hilos, python-requests

¡Hola! espero puedan ayudarme a comprender el problema que surge con el siguiente programa.

Recién estoy comenzando a trabajar con hilos y la idea es realizar una petición a una api que genera nombres aleatorios.

Esta petición se realiza 20 veces dentro de un ciclo for y evidentemente en cada ejecución imprime un nombre distinto. Si ejecuto el programa de forma secuencial no tengo mayor problema y se generan los 20 nombres.

El problema surge cuando hago uso de un thread, ya que aunque se ejecuta claramente mas rápido no imprime los 20 nombres sino que únicamente imprime 4 o 5 en distintas ocasiones. ¿Porqué puede suceder esto?.

Entiendo que al crear un hilo este comparte la información del proceso por lo que podría surgir un problema al compartir la información pero no se si existe alguna forma de solucionarlo.

Les dejo mi código. y de antemano les agradezco la respuesta:

```
import requests
import json
import threading

def get_name():
    url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    response = requests.get(url) #realizo la petición

    if response.status_code == 200: #verifico que todo esté en orden
        content = response.content #obtengo el contenido de la respuesta
        information = json.loads(content) #transformo es json a un diccionario
        results = information.get('results')
        name = results[0].get('name').get('first') #obtengo la clave nombre
        print(name) #imprimo el nombre

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(0,20):
        threading.Thread(target=get_name).start()
```

Comment: Si tu programa termina al finalizar el `for`, entonces, finalizan todos tus threads ya que el proceso principal finalizó. De los 20 que mandas algunos logran finalizar otros no. Tienes que esperar a que todos terminen ya sea haciendo un `.join` o en  todo caso, levantarlos como ^demonios`  agregando el parametro `daemon=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema inicial no es de los hilos, estos se están ejecutando correctamente. El problema es que tienes un `if` que no se cumple siempre.

En esta parte del código `if response.status_code == 200:`, le estás diciendo que si la respuesta de la página no es un 200, entonces no haga nada, **y eso es lo que sucede**, por eso no se te imprimen el resto de nombres.

He modificado tu código añadiendo un `else` que imprima los códigos respuesta de la página, para que te des cuenta:

```
import requests
import json
import threading

def get_name():
    url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    response = requests.get(url) #realizo la petición

    if response.status_code == 200: #verifico que todo esté en orden
        content = response.content #obtengo el contenido de la respuesta
        information = json.loads(content) #transformo es json a un diccionario
        results = information.get('results')
        name = results[0].get('name').get('first') #obtengo la clave nombre
        print(name) #imprimo el nombre
    else:
        print(f"Código de respuesta {response.status_code}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(20):
        threading.Thread(target=get_name).start()
```

**Salida:**

```
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Código de respuesta 503
Sandra
Código de respuesta 503
Marcel
Tiana
Jessie
Lerke
```

Esto sucede porque has "bombardeado" al servidor con 20 peticiones en una milesima de segundo, **el código 503 indica que el servidor no está listo para darte una respuesta.** Si quiere arreglarlo, puedes agregar una pausa, por ejemplo con la función `sleep`:

```
import requests
import json
import threading
from time import sleep

def get_name():
    url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/'
    response = requests.get(url) #realizo la petición

    if response.status_code == 200: #verifico que todo esté en orden
        content = response.content #obtengo el contenido de la respuesta
        information = json.loads(content) #transformo es json a un diccionario
        results = information.get('results')
        name = results[0].get('name').get('first') #obtengo la clave nombre
        print(name) #imprimo el nombre
    else:
        print(f"Código de respuesta {response.status_code}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(20):
        sleep(0.5)
        threading.Thread(target=get_name).start()
```

**Salida:**

```
Marcus
Ethan
Selma
Roy
Tony
Nalan
Eline
Kaya
Eeli
Mustafa
Same
Ethel
Afonsina
Charles
Karl-Jürgen
پوریا
Murat
Minttu
Ariane
Theodore
```

Comment: ¿No era necesario un `join`, entonces?

Comment: Como comenta @CandidMoe tal vez sería importante hacer mención del join. Aunque no es necesario en este ejemplo, es importante saber que que el interprete de Python hace un join implícito sobre todos los hilos con su atributo `daemon=False` (es su valor por defecto).

Comment: ¡Te agradezco mucho!. Me quedó super claro, lo pondré en práctica.

Comment: @CandidMoe @SergioC Es que el problema de la pregunta viene del lado del servidor, no de los hilos. En mi opinión no es necesario hacer un `join` ya que el proceso termina una vez acaba la ejecución, es decir, no es un flujo de trabajo complejo en el que unos hilos tengan que esperar información de otros.